# Hangman Python Repeats Functions

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, function

When I try to run the code it keeps repeating,"So far you have guessed" when I only want it to repeat once. The output for the name when a guess is made should be like : secret_word = hello , then after every word it should be h???o or h?ll?

```
def get_secret_word():
    while True:
        secret_word = input('Please enter a word to be guessed\nthat does not contain ? or whitespace:')
    if not ('?' in secret_word or ' ' in secret_word or secret_word == ''):
        return secret_word


def is_game_over(wrong_guess, secret_word, output, chars_guessed):
    if wrong_guess == 7:
        print('You failed to guess the secret word:', secret_word)
        return True
    for guess in secret_word:
        if guess in chars_guessed:
            output += guess
        else:
            output += '?'
    if not ('?' in output):
        print('You correctly guessed the secret word:', secret_word)
        return True
    else:
        return False


def display_hangman(wrong_guess):
    if wrong_guess == 1:
        print('\n |')
     elif wrong_guess == 2:
        print('\n |', '\n O')
     elif wrong_guess == 3:
        print('\n |', '\n O', '\n |')
     elif wrong_guess == 4:
        print('\n |', '\n O', '\n/|')
     elif wrong_guess == 5:
        print('\n |', '\n O', '\n/|\\')
     elif wrong_guess == 6:
        print('\n |', '\n O', '\n/|\\', '\n/')
     elif wrong_guess == 7:
        print('\n |', '\n O', '\n/|\\', '\n/', '\\')

def display_guess(secret_word, chars_guessed):
    output = ''

    for guess in secret_word:
        if guess in chars_guessed:
            output += guess
        else:
            output += '\nSo far you have guessed: '
            for guess in chars_guessed:
                output += guess + ","
                print(output.strip(","))

def get_guess(secret_word, chars_guessed):
    while True:

        guess_character = input('Please enter your next guess: ')
        if guess_character == '':
            print('You must enter a guess.')
            continue
        elif len(guess_character) > 1:
            print('You can only guess a single character.')
        elif guess_character in chars_guessed:
            print('You already guessed the character:', guess_character)
        else:
            return guess_character

def main():
    wrong_guess = 0
    chars_guessed = []
    secret_word = get_secret_word()
    output = ''

    while not is_game_over(wrong_guess, secret_word, output, chars_guessed):
        display_hangman(wrong_guess)
        display_guess(secret_word, chars_guessed)
        guess_character = get_guess(secret_word, chars_guessed)
        chars_guessed.append(guess_character)
        chars_guessed.sort()
        if not guess_character in secret_word:
            wrong_guess += 1
            return wrong_guess
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as written right now your code will just keep asking for a new secret word an infinite number of times, so you've not quite got your indentation correct yet.

Answer (score 0):

so issues that I can see  are:

indentation issues(as pointed out by some of the other posters already):
 - get_secret_word() function with the if statement
 - display_hangman() function with all the elif's

also with the below bit of code from the main function

```
 if not guess_character in secret_word:
            wrong_guess += 1
            return wrong_guess
            pass
```

this exits out of the app for me and as far as I can see the *return* and *pass* lines are not needed. The *return* exits from the main function when an incorrect guess is made and so *pass* is never reached and since the *wrong_guess* is a "global" variable in the main function the new count is available to everything in that function for the length of time that the function is active.

as for the repeated looping with displaying the users guesses  it is the way in how you are looping in the `display_guess()` function. in the case that the character being guessed is not in the secret word it loops over everything twice, once for the outer for loop and then again for the inner loop.

I think you should change the *display_guess()* to something like the below. this way a user will always see what they have previously guessed

```
def display_guess():
    output = "\nSo far you have guessed: "
    count = 0
    if len(chars_guessed) > 0:
        for guess in chars_guessed:

            if count < len(chars_guessed) and count != 0:
                output += ','
            output += guess
            count +=1
        print output
```

as for displaying the secret word with the guessed characters and the rest as ?'s, it doesn't seem that you are printing the value of the *output* variable from the *is_game_over()* function anywhere. i haven't tested it but adding a print just after that for loop should sort that out.

on a side note you might wish to add validation on user input as it excepts numbers and special characters

Comment: The only problem with it is that it doesn't display the guesses named so far.

Comment: Thank you. Any other problems that you see in the program?

Comment: apart from the suggestions in the last sentence I would add to that to probably default all input to lower case as H is not the same as h for a users guess. also should at in a sys.exit() so that your script exits's nicely.